# Are Integer, Boolean, etc. Java Objects singleton objects?

Tags: java, object, primitive

I tried to search for this but couldn't find an answer easily.

If we have multiple `Integer` Java objects corresponding to the same integer value--are they the same in memory?

Comment: flyweight inmutable objects

Comment: As EJP indicates, there are some interfaces (eg, `Integer.valueOf`) that will return "cached" (and hence shared) values in some cases, but `new` will always return a new instance, not a shared one.

Comment: Right, but what about things like: `Integer a = 5;` which I think would work. It seems that this is simply a shorthand for `new` and therefore they are not equal.

Comment: No, it's a shorthand for `Integer.valueOf()` actually, although it isn't specified in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) how it must be done.

Comment: Ah, I see. But we can't count on `Integer a = 5; Integer b = 5;` leading to `a == b`, even though `valueOf` sometimes returns a cached instance?

Comment: Fun fact, the cutoff point is around 127. Below 127 (and above -128), and a == b will probably be true. Outside that range, it'll probably be false. Don't ever depend on that fact, though.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough It's stronger than that. From the [Javadoc:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) "This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but if you use `Integer.valueOf(),` `Long.valueOf(),` etc you may get single cached values. Not the same thing.

Comment: You may as in you will, or you may as in it's not guaranteed?

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you create them like this

```
Integer a = new Integer(5);
Integer b = a;
Integer c = b;
```

In the above case, `a`, `b`, and `c`, would all refer to the same `Integer` object.

If, on the other hand, you declare them like this

```
Integer a = new Integer(5);
Integer b = new Integer(5);
Integer c = new Integer(5);
```

then the 3 variables, `a`, `b`, and `c` all refer to separate `Integer` object.